# Snowflake CHANGES | Why does it need to perform a self join? Why is it slower than join using other unique column?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bigdata

I was facing issues with merge statement over large tables.
The source table for merge is basically clone of the target table after applying some DML.

e.g. In the below example PUBLIC.customer is target and STAGING.customer is the source.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE STAGING.customer CLONE PUBLIC.customer;
MERGE INTO STAGING.customer TARGET USING (SELECT * FROM NEW_CUSTOMER) AS SOURCE ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID 
 WHEN MATCHED AND SOURCE.DELETEFLAG=TRUE THEN DELETE
 WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.ROWMODIFIED < SOURCE.ROWMODIFIED THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.AGE = SOURCE.AGE, ...
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (AGE) VALUES (AGE, DELETEFLAG, ID,...);
```

Currently, we are simply merging the STAGING.customer back to PUBLIC.customer at the end.
This final merge statement is very costly for some of the large tables.

While looking for a solution to reduce the cost, I discovered Snowflake "CHANGES" mechanism. As per the documentation,

> Currently, at least one of the following must be true before change tracking metadata is recorded for a table:

1. Change tracking is enabled on the table (using ALTER TABLE … CHANGE_TRACKING = TRUE).
2. A stream is created for the table (using CREATE STREAM).

> Both options add hidden columns to the table which store change tracking metadata. The columns consume a small amount of storage.

I assumed that the metadata added to the table is equivalent to the result-set of the select statement using "changes" clause, which doesn't seem to be the case.

```sql
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.CUSTOMER(AGE,...) (SELECT AGE,... FROM STAGING.CUSTOMER  CHANGES (information => default) at(timestamp => 1675772176::timestamp) where "METADATA$ACTION" = 'INSERT' );
```

The select statement using "changes" clause is way slower than the merge statement that I am using currently.

I checked the execution plan and found that Snowflake performs a self-join(sort of) on the table at two different timestamp.
[image: execution-plan-for-insert-statement]

Should it really be the behaviour or am I missing something here? I was hoping to get better performance assuming to scan the table one time and then simply inserting the new records which should be faster than the merge statement.

Also, even if it does a self join, why does the merge query perform better than this, the merge query is also doing join on similar volumes.
[image: merge-query-plan]

I was also hoping to use same mechanism for delete/updates on source table.

Comment: The self join is done because of the Stream which needs to check what are the changes on the table between the previous consumption of the stream and the current one.

Comment: If you only care about the inserts as your example seems to indicate, then rather than using CHANGES, create a STREAM that is append-only.  This avoids the join back, since you are only looking at new records.

Comment: Well I need insert/update/delete all of them. I also observed, the merge statement that I am using in final merge between stage and public are equivalent in volume, and it also needs to perform join of these two tables, but this join is way faster than the `changes` one. To clarify, there is no optimisation performed on the join column and `id` column in this case.